# for each problem in ansible jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

ansible version: 2.10.9

role:

```
-name: set fact
 set_fact:
   fruits: '["banana","apple"]'
```

template:

```
{%- for fruit in fruits -%}
  {{ fruit }},
{%- endfor -%}
```

expected outputs:

```
banana,apple,
```

but what I actually got:

```
[,",b,a,n,a,n,a,",,,",a,p,p,l,e,"],
```

can someone explains why all the character has separated by comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fruits: '["banana","apple"]'
```

it means fruits is a string, but you want to define fruits as a list, so please remove `''`.

Answer (score 1):

just a guess but it's probably related to the `''` surrounding your object

Please try it like this

```
-name: set fact
 set_fact:
   fruits: ["banana","apple"]
```